# Django: move all previously uploaded media files to new location and rename

Tags: python, django

So, I'm using Django (1.10) and I've got a few hundred uploaded (media) files. I want to move and rename all the files, because I want to slightly change the folder structure.

In my models.py, I do have a perfectly working save() method that saves the files in the correct location, but it only works on new files. I want to move all already-existing files.

I hoped that by just calling the save method on all the objects, it would automatically move and rename the files, but that didn't do anything (like I kinda expected).

Is there an easy way to do this? I have the feeling I'm overlooking a really straight-forward solution...

Comment: Just `mv` or `cp` files to new directory + rename them in terminal. Well in django just replace path afterwards?

Comment: Hmm, maybe that wasn't completely clear, but the files should be removed/renamed based on other information stored in the database/models.py. So, just moving them 'manually' is not really possible I think.

Comment: Give more information then. What are your files names/dir structure in db now? What should they look like?

Comment: Well, in my models.py is a model called File. A file has(obviously) a FileField and a bunch of other fields for information about that file, such as the author, the name of the object its about etc.

The old structure was: / [theme-name] / [number] / [number] - [name].txt

The new structure should be: / [theme-name] / [number] - [name] / [number] - [name].txt

And besides that, the theme-names have also changed for already uploaded files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you will have to do some scripting here. You can use django-extensions here. 
https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions
You can setup the same in your project
Assuming your model `File`

Write a script let's `migrate_media_files.py`

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from shutil import copyfile


def run():
    base_dir = settings.BASE_DIR
    media_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,'project_name/media')

    for file in Files.objects.all():
        old_file_path = os.path.join(media_dir, file.image.name)
        dir_name = '/{}-{}/{}-{}/'.format(file.theme,file.name,file.id, file.name)
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(media_dir, dir_name)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(media_dir, dir_name))
        new_file_name = '/{}-{}/{}-{}/{}-{}.txt'.format(file.theme,file.name,file.id, file.name, file.id, file.name)
        new_file_path = os.path.join(media_dir, new_file_name)
        copyfile(old_file_path, new_file_path)
        file.image.url = new_file_name
        file.save()
```

To run :

```
python manage.py runscript migrate_file
```

This script mainly plays with files and your objects. You might need changes and testing. All the best.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the help :) I tried getting it to work, but I keep getting a Django SuspiciousFileOperation warning at the os.path.join line for the old_path_file. It says that the joined path is outside the project folder (which the printed line in the console is). I have no idea where that error is coming from (the media_dir looks fine when printed).

Comment: As said i haven't test. file.images gives the image object. edited the answer to use file.image.name to get the path.  We can come on chat or hoping for you update the working answer.

Comment: Ok, I got it working successfully now. The suspicious file error was kinda stupid. Apparently, it already moved all files in one of the earlier runs, but I didn't notice that. Because of a small error, all files were moved to folders in the root folder of the drive. I removed them and replaced the (now 'broken') database with a backup. Ran the program again and they were moved to the root again. I finally found the source of the problem: dir_name and new_file_name should not start with a / otherwise os.join kinda fails apparently.

Comment: So, in short, things I changed: removed the starting / in dir_name and new_file_name, used settings.MEDIA_ROOT instead of creating manually creating a custom media_dir and slightly altered the naming scheme (but that's optional obviously). Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. You should update the answer with fixes that you did.