# Share media between multiple django(VMs) servers

Tags: python, django

We have deployed a django server (nginx/gunicorn/django) but to scale the server there are multiple instances of same django application running.

Here is the diagram (architecture):

[image]

Each blue rectangle is a Virtual Machine.

HAProxy sends all request to example.com/admin to Server 3.other requests are divided between Server 1 and Server 2.(load balance).

**Old Problem:**

Each machine has a media folder and when admin Uploads something the uploaded media is only on Server 3. (normal users can't upload anything)

We solved this by sending all requests to example.com/media/* to Server 3 and nginx from Server3 serves all static files and media.

**Problem right now**

We are also using sorl-thumbnail.

When a requests comes for example.com/,sorl-thumbnail tries to access the media file but it doesn't exist on this machine because it's on Server3.

So now all requests to that machine(server 1 or 2) get 404 for that media file.

One solution that comes to mind is to make a shared partition between all 3 machines and use it as media.
Another solution is to sync all media folders after each upload but this solution has problem and that is we have almost 2000 requests per second and sometimes sync might not be fast enough and sorl-thumbnail creates the database record of empty file and 404 happens.

Thanks in advance and sorry for long question.

Comment: We're using a separate machine for static and media that is NFS mounted to the application servers. It works, but we don't have nearly your load...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an object store to save and serve your user uploaded files. [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) makes the implementation really simple.

If you don’t want to use cloud based AWS S3 or equivalent, you can host your own on-prem S3 compatible object store with [minio](https://min.io/).

On your current setup I don’t see any easy way to fix where the number of vm s are dynamic depending on load.

If you have deployment automation then maybe try out [rsync](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) so that the vm takes care of syncing files with other vms.

Comment: seems like  minio and django-storage is solution but problem is migrating.what can I do about it? is it okay and possible to create a VM that is connected to minio and replace my current VMs one by one?

Comment: How much data do you have? is it same in all the 3 VMs? Nevertheless, you should always treat infrastructure as "cattle not pets" https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-definition-of-cattle-not-pets . Minio is another beast which needs to be maintained/scaled in the long run and I would highly recommend to use something like AWS S3, DigitalOcean Spaces (pretty much all cloud providers have S3 compatible Object Store offering). You also get free automatic CDN with most of these.

Comment: media is same across all VMs and as I said normal users can't upload anything so It's only admins. right now it's about 4 GB and raising and mostly Images.problem is we don't have access to AWS s3 or other services and running a minio is a better and more stable solution.

Comment: For migration, you need to do a little bit of research and scripting. I haven’t done this before but this can be a starting point https://stackoverflow.com/a/42188942

Comment: Or if it's too much go with the shared partition. I don't see any big advantage with all these migrations and minio and making things so complex. Specially when you don't get any CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Question: What was the problem?

we got 404 on other machines because normal requests (requests asking for a template) would get a 404 not found on thumbnail media.
real problem was with sorl-thumbnail template tags.

Here is what we ended up doing:

In models that needed a thumbnail, we added functions to create that specific thumbnail.

and using a [post-save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-save) [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch) in the admin machine called all those functions to make sure all the thumbnails were created after save and the table for sorl-thumbnail is filled.

now in templates instead of calling sorl-thumbnail template tags now we call a function in model.